# Windows Split Desktop Utility

Tags: windows, desktop

Is there such a thing?  I don't want multiple separate desktops, what I'd like to be able to do is split my main desktop into two areas so that an application in one when maximized won't take up the "Full" physical screen, but its portion of it.

I would like to be able to keep some apps maximized, but still view others off to the side with a single monitor.

Ideas?

Comment: I can see how this could be particularly useful on **huge** monitors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [WinSplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/).  It's got some great default settings for window locations/sizes, but is also fully customizable.  I'm using it for coding on dual monitors, but have also used it on a single monitor and it works great for that too.

Comment: Seems like this links to the MaxTo program now.

Answer (score 9):

[MaxTo](http://maxto.net/) - MaxTo is a program that lets you maximize windows to different parts of your monitor. Ideal for programmers, graphic designers and anyone else who needs to have many windows visible at once.

Works very stable.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. :) (PS! I am the developer behind MaxTo)

Comment: Can it do same in fullscreen too? To use multiple gpus one per each?

Answer (score 4):

Are you thinking about something like [Windows Snap](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/snap)?

I don't have a program to do that but [DisplayFusion](http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/) does include options to snap windows to the sides and corners of the monitor (and some clever middle-click/drag options to switch maximised windows to another monitor).

Comment: No, not quite Snap (love that feature of Windows 7 BTW).  This is more dedicated "subscreen" zones.

Answer (score 3):

I use a free utility called [GridMove](http://jgpaiva.dcmembers.com/gridmove.html) with success. It allows you to position and size windows to sections/areas of your monitors. And the templates that it uses are customizable.

I use a [grid created by user 'excogitation' on the forums](http://www.donationcoder.com/Forums/bb/index.php?topic=11534.msg99778#msg99778) (look for the download links at the bottom of his post)

Comment: FYI, I've since switched to WinSplit Revolution

Answer (score 0):

It is only a sample program for a .NET library...,
but I like [NeatKeys](http://mwinapi.sourceforge.net/tools.html) for resizing windows so that they align to each other (for presentations etc.). There are several modes (one with presets like Winsplit Revolution, one where you draw lines and then assign your windows to the existing rectangles, and one where you can just save current sizes and attach shortcuts to them). Most features can be used both by keyboard and by mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I use GridMove, but I also find [allSnap](http://ivanheckman.com/allsnap/) helpful for maximizing real estate in one-time configurations.