# Desktop space reservation

Tags: windows, desktop, workspace

This might be a bit of a stretch, but is there some software or method available to reserve desktop space, but allow certain programs to use it? Sort of like dividing the desktop so that maximizing a program only takes up a certain amount of the screen?

EDIT: if at all possible I'd like to be able to maximize another window inside the reserved space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand. Are you lookign for something like this: [MaxTo](http://maxto.net/)

There is a few more of them here: [Windows Split Desktop Utility](https://superuser.com/questions/1649/windows-split-desktop-utility)

Answer (score 1):

this CAN be done with JetToolBar, which is a freeware. This will install a sort of toolbar / launcher, which is what it is. What you need to do next is run this toolbar as NOT always-on-top (just see the program options), and use another program to run the program that you want to run (that I don't know of but any will do) as 'Always on top'. (See download.com, many program can make another one run on top of others).

Answer (score 0):

On windows?  Not that I know of.

On Linux, Enlightenment can do this, with specially designated areas for icons etc.  I don't know if it was implemented or not, but I think there was talk of thinking these desktop layouts with wallpapers, so your icons could avoid the nice/complex parts of your background.

KDE can do it a little too, with plasma containers.  There is a windows port of KDE, but that's still quite new, so I wouldn't really recommend trying it yet.

OR, you could probably make a desktop file manager like nautilus run in non-root-window mode, so it's tiled beside other windows.  A tiling window manager would make this very easy to keep alongside other windows without them overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

unless you're working with virtual machines, this is not possible in windows.

you can use **[Actual Window Manager](http://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/)**, which will do the following:

> placing windows exactly to the
>   required place
>
> sizing them exactly as they should be

*Actual Window Manager is shareware, try before you buy.*

a free alternative would be Eusing's **[Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm)**. not as powerful though.