# A software to lock regions of a screen to prevent any windows from overlapping

Tags: windows, display, workspace

I've just installed nexus dock (a similar application like rocketdock), after playing with the preferences i've come across a very curious option (under position & behavior) that says: Prevent maximized windows from overlapping the dock. With it enabled, any application I maximize(and i do mean *any*) won't overlap the dock, it's really great. So i'm thinking perhaps there's a software that does this kind of feature which is really ideal for keeping my workspace really organized. I really hate repositioning and resizing my windows everytime. Of course there's always the manual way of doing these but it's just too much of a bother when someone from the family uses the computer.

Do you know any software that does this? even a software that can just save/remember window positions would also be nice too.

Comment: you should check out `possible duplicate` http://superuser.com/questions/62248/desktop-space-reservation

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a [Tiling Window Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager). Windows doesn't include this in any real usable way but it can be accomplished using 3rd party software.

In Windows I use [Winsplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/). It doesn't prevent overlapping but it does give you shortcut keys to snap windows to set positions on the screen. The shortcut keys and window positions are all configurable.