# Better window arrangement for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, themes, gui

Does anyone know of a tool or plugin for Windows XP that allows me to "dock" a window on one half of the screen, as if that half were an entirely separate display?  Ideally, I'd like to be able to drag a window to the left, maximize it, and have it fill up the entire left half of the screen.

Has anyone ever seen or heard of anything like this?

Comment: Possible Dupe- http://superuser.com/questions/1649/windows-split-desktop-utility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [AeroSnap application](http://aerosnap.de/index_eng.htm) that brings Windows 7's AeroSnap feature to Windows XP and Vista.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Give [GridMove](http://gridmove.en.softonic.com/) a try - it's free.

> GridMove helps you by defining a
>   visual grid on your desktop, to which
>   you can easily snap windows. This
>   means you can separate sections of
>   your desktop into specific areas.
>   GridMove allows you to move windows,
>   re-size them, displaying them in a
>   cascade or mosaic or making them stay
>   permanently on top simply by dragging
>   and dropping.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you install [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (free), you can download and install [Windows 7 Shortcuts on XP](http://lifehacker.com/5133039/windows-7-shortcuts-enables-the-best-win7-shortcuts-in-xp-or-vista) (also free).

> Included:
> Win+Left/Right arrows: **Dock
>   the window to each side of the monitor**
>   Win+Up arrow: Maximize the active
>   window
>  Win+Down arrow: Minimize the
>   window/Restore the window if it's
>   maximized
>  Win+Space: All windows are
>   made transparent so you can see the
>   desktop
>  Win+Home: Minimize all windows
>   but the current window

Answer (score 0):

I love [Winsplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/).  It features keyboard shortcuts, multi-monitor support and more.  I haven't looked back since I installed it.

[image]

I personally use the keyboard shortcuts to move my windows.

Ctrl+Alt+W to maximize

Ctrl+Alt+Q/R for left/right side of the screen

Ctrl+Alt+LeftArrow/RightArrow to move between monitors

Answer (score 0):

PowerResizer described [here](http://www.freewaregenius.com/2009/04/21/powerresizer-snap-windows-to-the-screens-edge-and-resize-them-relative-to-each-other/):

> PowerResizer is a free program that
>   brings the window resizing/docking
>   function popularized by Windows 7 to
>   all Windows platforms. It is unique in
>   that once two windows are docked
>   PowerResizer will let you grab ahold
>   of any one of the edges in the
>   ”border” are between the two Windows
>   and drag it to resize both windows
>   simultaneously, in case you wanted one
>   of them to take up a larger area than
>   the other. A really nifty feature.
>   Additionally, you can perform all
>   sorts of resizing behaviors using a
>   combination of resizing and hotkeys.

[image: image1]

Another useful utility is [AllSnap](http://ivanheckman.com/allsnap/):

> This program will make windows that
>   you might move around your desktop
>   ’snap together’ (as, for example, they
>   do with WinAmp), or snap to desktop.
>   You can set the threshold in pixels in
>   the settings, and once your window is
>   within the range you define the
>   snapping-to-grid will take effect. It
>   can also prevent any Windows from
>   going off the screen. You can press
>   the Alt key (user definable) in order
>   to suspend the snapping action and
>   move windows normally.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [**Actual Window Manager**](http://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/) for my 'window arrangement' needs.

It has multiple monitor support (including taskbar and start button), multiple virtual desktops, customize settings for each and every window to your liking ... a fantastic piece of software (unfortunately, it isn't free).

[image]

For a more basic (and free) variant, have a look at Eusing's [Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm).

[image]