# Software or hardware solution for virtual monitors, on one physical monitor

Tags: windows-7, display

So here's the situation: I run live streams of video games, and I'd like to be able to read the stream chat and control my broadcast software while streaming, but with a fullscreen game this is extremely difficult. Some games can't be minimized, others will cause the stream to freeze while I'm minimized.

A lot of livestreamers use dual monitors to deal with this, they can stream from one monitor, and do the other things the audience shouldn't be watching on the other monitor, and it has the added effect of not breaking fullscreen games.

Unfortunately, due to space constraints it's not really feasible for me to get a second monitor right now. I figure there has to be someone else out there who had the same thought I did: virtual monitor. Is there anything that exists, software or hardware that would allow me to have two "virtual" monitors on one physical monitor? I figure I could use something similar to a KVM switch, or a software solution, but I don't really know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Windows Split Desktop Utility](http://superuser.com/questions/1649/windows-split-desktop-utility)

Comment: [Is there a way to fake a dual (second) monitor](http://superuser.com/questions/62051/is-there-a-way-to-fake-a-dual-second-monitor)

Comment: [Virtual Screen Splitter](http://superuser.com/questions/412588/virtual-screen-splitter)

Comment: [Is there a way to split a widescreen monitor in to two or more virtual monitors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354488/is-there-a-way-to-split-a-widescreen-monitor-in-to-two-or-more-virtual-monitors)

Comment: If you're willing to pay, I personally consider [this](http://www.ishadow.com/?tabid=115) to be one of the more reliable looking options (it's also in at least two of the answers to the above questions). If nothing in this list works, please comment saying why. If one works, please comment saying so and we'll have this question closed as a duplicate (or you can flag for moderator attention to that effect).