# Is there a way to create "logical" monitors without sacrificing performance?

Tags: display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, performance, gpu

I'm in an odd situation, where it would be beneficial to be able to take a single 3840x1080 monitor and have Windows treat it as if it was actually two 1920x1080 monitors - one as the Windows "default" display and the second as a normal extended display, allowing applications to be maximized to one or the other etc.
**EDIT:** I'm specifically looking for a way to make the OS treat two areas of my monitor as if they were physically separate displays - just making the windows snap to one side or the other is not enough to resolve this issue. Therefore this is not a duplicate of [Windows Split Desktop Utility [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/1649/windows-split-desktop-utility)

I'd want the GPU to operate as close to normally as possible, with maximum GPU performance on both of the "logical" displays.

Is there any way to accomplish this within the OS?
Would custom code be necessary?
(If so, this is not a total deal breaker.)

The GPU being used here is the NVIDIA GTX 860M 4GB

Comment: Typically what you describe is done in hardware by having two input ports on the ultra-wide monitor.  If the GPU is capable of driving dual monitors, then all you need are two cables to the monitor, and then setup Windows with two monitors.

Comment: @sawdust I understand what you mean, but unfortunately my situation won't allow for this. I have only one HDMI output, which cannot be split or daisy-chained (to my knowledge). I am able to get the 3840x1080 resolution from the single output, but I need to have the software (Windows or the video drivers) split it into two displays that function as if they were separate physical monitors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Split Desktop Utility](http://superuser.com/questions/1649/windows-split-desktop-utility). Also see http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000894.htm

Comment: @sawdust Thanks, but you seem to presume I don't really need the OS to treat the monitor as two separate displays. If I didn't need this, I wouldn't have specifically asked about it. Neither the ComputerHope article nor the previous question you mentioned are relevant. Please remove the duplicate flag from this question unless you can find a previous question that is relevant to the issue I've described. I have edited the question to further clarify this. If you really want other readers to be aware of those other options, feel free to leave those recommendations in the comments.

Comment: One product that cannot do it in SW alone: http://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/fullscreen-video-in-split-window/?ID=58d293bf-a1fe-4b2a-be82-c770407005d5